# Terminal command will not execute after boot

Tags: raspbian, boot, web-server, server

I have a raspberry pi which I want to turn into a web server. I have installed everything needed. Now my problem: I am using `ngrok` to get the server online. To do this all I have to do is running the following command in the terminal:

```
/home/pi/Downloads/ngrok http -subdomain=asimpledomain 80
```

Now I want this command to be executed on startup so I changed my rc.local file to this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.


/home/pi/Downloads/ngrok http -subdomain=asimpledomain 80 &

exit 0
```

I have saved the files and rebooted but after booting up I found out that this is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: I have no idea.  It might help if you say in your post what you expected to happen and how you know it's not working.  As a side question why not just do sudo apt-get install apache2?

Comment: apache2 is instaleed.What i expect is when pi has boot an ngrok tunnel to be created

Comment: As a matter of interest did you install ngrok from the Raspbian repository?  I'd have assumed it would handle the initialisation automatically.

Comment: how can i install ngrok from repo?

Comment: apt-cache search ngrok shows ngrok-client and ngrok-server packages.  Install the one(s) you want with sudo apt-get install ngrok-client and/or sudo apt-get install ngrok-server.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try running a test to see if it throws errors without a reboot:

```
sudo service rc.local start
```

then check it from there. You may have to run it as a specific user:

```
sudo -u pi /home/pi/Downloads/ngrok http -subdomain=asimpledomain 80 &
```

Comment: So if **service rc.local start** doesn't show an error, then it should execute correctly upon every boot of pi?  Ngrok doesn't start for me.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried exporting the path variables in the `bashrc` files?

My best guess is you do the following:

1. put the `ngrok`directory in a `bin/` directory in `/home/pi`

   ```
   mkdir bin
   ```
2. give it executable mode

   ```
   sudo chmod +x bin/
   ```
3. change path variables in `.bashrc`

   ```
   sudo nano ~/.bashrc
   # at the end of the file
   export PATH=$PATH:bin/
   ```
4. press `CTRL+O` and `CTRL+X` and then

   ```
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```

and maybe try rebooting it again.

I somehow think that maybe there might be problems with path variable settings.

Answer (score 0):

Have to tried accessing website without reboot and without modifying rc.local?

I suppose you can opt for crontab instead of rc.local..

crontab entry via `crontab -e`:

```
@reboot /home/pi/Downloads/ngrok http -subdomain=asimpledomain 80 & > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: what is > /dev/null 2>&1?

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/10508862/4870299

Comment: I tried this but it is not working

Comment: Do you have paid account in ngrok?
AFAIK ngrok allows own subdomain in paid account.

For free account, try this command

/home/pi/Downloads/ngrok tcp 80

See active tunnels with this command (if ngrok running in backgound)

curl http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels

Comment: I don't need a paid account.If I try this from a terminal it works

Comment: i presume issue was with initiating ngrok via terminal.
So disable console ui for ngrok by editing **ngrok.yml** file in **/home/pi/.ngrok2**
create cron entry for user 'pi' and user 'pi' should have execute permissions

Comment: How can I di this